# Is it possible pause & resume for Retrofit multipart request?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

We are using Retrofit multi-part for file uploading process.

We want pause/resume when file uploading.

I want to know its possible or not?

**Code for multi-part file upload**

```
  RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

  // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
  MultipartBody.Part body =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);
  Call<ResponseBody> call= api.uploadFile(body);
```

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips on how to improve your question. In particular, "is it possible" is not specific enough for this site.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I clearly asked specific question. Its not broad question & I don't ask tutorial or code something.

Comment: You can look at this :https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49364158/7123413

Answer (score 8):

Yes its possible. You would have to create your own request body.

```
   public class PausableRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    private File mFile;
    private long uploadedData;

    public PausableRequestBody(final File file) {
        mFile = file;
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        return MediaType.parse("image/*");
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() throws IOException {
        return mFile.length();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink bs) throws IOException {
        long fileLength = mFile.length();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFile);

        try {
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                this.uploadedData += read;
                bs.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    public long getUploadedData() {
        return uploadedData;
    }
}
```

use append instead of write..

**Use following Retrofit call**

```
PausableRequestBody fileBody = new PausableRequestBody(file, this);
        MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileBody);

        Call<JsonObject> request = RetrofitClient.uploadImage(filepart);
        request.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>{...});
```

**to pause the request** you would have to cancel the call
request.cancel()

**to restart**
use the same PausableRequestBody object with the same method mentioned above

Comment: Where is pause request?

Comment: to pause you need to cancel the request mentioned above.

Comment: If I restart it will start from first or paused position?

Comment: for that you need to append instead of write.

Comment: did it helped.?

Comment: sry to say! I am not understand where I need to append instead off write.

Comment: If I give bs.append() -> it will continue from paused position? unbelievable.. I will offer you bounty.. can you give detailed answer. I hope it looks working solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177026/discussion-between-kunal-mahajan-and-ranjith-kumar).

Comment: Hey, sorry dear, I thought you found a solution. Will that be possible to share your code, I will work on it. ?

Comment: ok bro. when you free only give me the answer. no need to stop/hold your work

Comment: thank you @Ranjith, you are awesome. In mean if possible share your code either on github here.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [***Jake Wharton from Square***](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2800),

There is no built-in pause or resume for retrofit.

If you want to stick on to retrofit then you may need to make your backend to support `range requests`. This can help you to break the connection at any time during a streaming download. You can then use the range headers in every subsequent requests to support `pause or resume download`.

You may also check this answer using [using okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43352569/8009433)